# How to make my grid of buttons respond to clicks

Tags: java, jpanel

I'm currently coding a battleship game and my UI involves a two dimensional grid of buttons. I'm trying to make it so that when each button is clicked then the coordinates of that button are sent to another method to execute the necessary command. However, I can't figure out how to make each button respond to clicks at specific times. Here's a bit of the code that applies to my question:

```
    JPanel userFrame = new JPanel();
    userFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    JButton[][] userGrid = new JButton[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            userGrid[i][j] = new JButton("(" + i + ", " + j + ")");
            userFrame.add(userGrid[i][j]);
        }
    }


    contentPane.add(userFrame);

    JPanel computerFrame = new JPanel();
    computerFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    JButton[][] computerGrid = new JButton[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            computerGrid[i][j] = new JButton("(" + i + " ," + j + ")");
            computerFrame.add(computerGrid[i][j]);
        }
    }
    contentPane.add(computerFrame);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!